# PHP - Filter keywords and values from a text

Tags: php

Im wondering whats the best method to extract some information from a LONGTEXT. I have a example below with the text. Want i want to extract is a list with DJ's, Music Genres and the age.

The text is received from a string.

#### Example text:

> Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla faciliti.
>
> Minimal age: 21
>
> Tickets:
>
> Regular Presale Ticket - € 10,-
>   Special Lady Ticket (2 for 1) - € 15,-
>   Groupticket (5 Pers) - € 45,-
>
> Muziek genres:
>
> | Salsa | Merengue | Urban | Eclectic | Kizomba | Bachata | Dancehall | Reggaeton |
>
> DJ’s:
>
> | Vato Gonzales | Afrojack | Blasterjaxx | Paul Elstak |

Comment: This is a very general question, kind of "please do this for me". Please google for regular expressions (regex), which is what you're looking for. If you have any specific problems, you can come back of course.

Comment: I almost agree with you but the first line is a question: How can i do this the best. Currently im exploding each line, use a foreach and use a strpos to check if the string contains specific words. Thats why i ask "What is the best way to handle this"